# Where can I find the definition of the macro __insn_dword_align that occurs in memcmp.c of the glibc source code project?

Tags: alignment, glibc, memcmp

The implementation of function memcmp in glibc uses the macro DBLALIGN(eg, DBLALIG(a3, a0, srcli)) to compare two unsinged int integer. DBLALIGN is delcared as follows. However, the definition of __insn_dword_align is not found in glibc source codes. Where can I find it. Thank you!

```
#ifdef __tilegx__
#define DBLALIGN __insn_dblalign
#define REVBYTES __insn_revbytes
#else
#define DBLALIGN __insn_dword_align
#define REVBYTES __insn_bytex
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a gcc builtin. See e.g. [here](http://cgit.haiku-os.org/buildtools/plain/gcc/gcc/config/tilepro/tilepro.c).

> I cannot find the definition

You wouldn't find a definition for any builtin. That's what "builtin" means: the compiler recognizes builtin by name and emits required instructions directly to assembly.

Comment: I find it in your link. But I cannot find the definition of __insn_dword_align. Event if i download gcc 4.4.7 source code and search the definition of __insn_dword_align. Are the builtins implemented in assembly language? I want the final implementaton of the macro. And How can I do? Thanks a lot.